# Image gallery hoover effect

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I have zero programming knowledge but I am building a website using HTML code. I have an image gallery on this site and I found some code to create a hoover effect. When you hoover over an image a dark but transparent box will appear and some text that is adjustable. The problem for me is that the position of the text over each image depends on the amount of text. If there is a lot of text, the text will start at a fixed distance from the left. But if there is few text, it will be centralised. I am trying to adjust the code in such a way that the text will start at a fixed distance from the left independent of the amount of text.

I hope that my question is somewhat clear, there must be an easy solution for this I guess. The code from the CSS is as follows:

```
.image-gallery .gallery_card > a {
    position: relative;
}

.image-gallery .gallery_card .gallery_image_caption {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    padding: 0.4rem 0.4rem 0.4rem 1.0rem;
    margin: 0.8rem;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    opacity: 0;
}

.image-gallery .gallery_image_caption span {
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.image-gallery .gallery_card:hover .gallery_image_caption {
    opacity: 1;
}

body.mobile .image-gallery .gallery_card:hover .gallery_image_caption {
    opacity: 0;
}

.gallery_card {
    position: relative;
}

.gallery_image_caption {
    pointer-events: none !important;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just assign the zoom class to image

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

Comment: If I add this text in the CSS it will give an error. Like I said I do not know anything about programming. I would have to work from the code that I have.

Comment: please share you html too after that i will complete the code for you

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot access the HTML, I am building my website using Cargo. I added the code to the CSS and it actually works just fine, apart from that the image captions will be centered if there is little text. I thought this would be directly adjustable by the code that I provided, by changing perhaps the "align-content: center" to "align-content: left", but this doesn't change anything